# How to filter a string field containing date to get last 10 days data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is the document structure in the collection, from this I need to filter using *createdTime* which is of type string, to get last 10 days records from the collection.

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
    "data" : {
        "name" : "abc",
        "createdTime" : "2021-02-19T05:13:29.351+00:00",
        "payloadVersion" : "1.0"
    },
    "detail" : {
        "event" : "XYZ",
        "spocId" : 1244,
        "deviceId" : "12345"
    }
}
```

The DB name is TEST and tried this query

> db.TEST.find({"data.createdTime":{"gte":new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-10))}})

but it is not giving any results. What is the best possible solution for this without changing the type of date field from string to date?

Comment: You will need to build the string that represents 10 days ago, and pass that in the query instead of a Date object

Comment: Yes its working when I passed date as string!!! Thanks a lot.